# HTML5 element that allowed be anywere

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, ejs

I am [developing](https://github.com/Enelar/phoxy) library, that helps dynamicly loading design.

Here the little example:

A.EJS

```
This is the a.ejs file
```

B.EJS

```
<b><%= phoxy.DeferRender('a', {}) %></b>
```

Will be staged as

```
<b><div id="phoxy_defer_render_4523fkdjfdfsi"></div></b>
```

And rendered(as soon as design loaded) as

```
<b>This is a.ejs file</b>
```

Here the problem. If i am using that construction

```
<table><%= phoxy.DeferRender('a', {}) %></table>
```

then i gets wrong design, cause `<div>` permitted to be in `<table>`.

Question:
with what HTML element i should straight my goals?
OR
what element allowed to be both inside and outside `<table>` element?

Comment: I think it's highly likely that you will eventually be rendering other elements besides `<div>`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, correct me if I'm wrong but I think that Offenso is trying to simply use any element as a placeholder so the specific element type is only relevant to the validity of the markup in the interim.

Comment: @Brian-Peacock, true.
Currently Chrome/Opera + FF markup like this:
<div id="phoxy_defer_render_4523fkdjfdfsi"></div><table></table>

Answer (score 1):

It's kinda messy but the W3C validator says that a `<script>` tag will work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <script type="text/html" id="phoxy_defer_render_4523fkdjfdfsi"></script>
    </table>
    <ol>
      <script type="text/html" id="phoxy_defer_render_anothertag"></script>
    </ol>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can check at http://validator.w3.org/check

Comment: What the hack! So unobvious solution. Thanks. If no alternatives available, ill use this tag.

Comment: Just had the occasion to actually use this little hack, funny how these things come around

Answer (score 0):

The problem you will face is that there are certain HTML elements that require particular child elements.

What immediately springs to mind are:

`ul` and `ol` required their immediate decendents to be `li`.

`dl` requires `dt` or `dd`

`table` reqires `thead`, `tbody` & `tfoot` with their children limited to `tr` then is children of `td`.

Using anything other than those will result in invalid HTML and inconsitant behavior across browsers.

The closest thing I can think of as a catch all would be `<span>` but it will still not be valid HTML for all circumstances.